# Combining several geometric regions by adding pointwise?

Tags: regions

Given two regions $D_1, D_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, I'm looking to combine them by adding pointwise:
$$D_1 + D_2 := \left\{ (a+x, b+y) \mid (a,b) \in D_1, (x,y) \in D_2 \right\}.$$ Even more generally, given a map $f:\mathbb{R}^l \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$, combine the regions $D_1\subseteq \mathbb{R}^l, D_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ using $f$ over all pointwise combinations:
$$f(D_1 , D_2) := \left\{ f (\vec{a}, \vec{x} ) \mid \vec{a} \in D_1, \vec{x} \in D_2 \right\}.$$

Is there an elegant way to do this in Mathematica? Something like `f[r1,r2]` or `Outer[f, r1,r2,1]`? Here's a MWE and the closest I've been able to come (which works, but feels clunky). My approach is to explicitly construct the Cartesian product using `RegionProduct` and then apply a mapping `f` using `TransformedRegion`

`r1=Rectangle[]; r2=Disk[]; 
f[{a_,b_,x_,y_}]:={a+x,b+y}
Region@TransformedRegion[RegionProduct[r1, r2], f]`

[image: Combined Regions]

Surely there's a built-in function or piece of syntax I'm missing?